# Command button in Excel to make a copy of a row of data and move that row to a different tab in the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get a command button that is placed on a worksheet in Excel that will transfer a line of data to a different sheet based on a certain field in a field. For example I have all the data in a row that has 6 different fields and one is names Type. Then I have worksheets that have the same names as all the Type options. What I want to happen is the user press and update button and the Type for each row is located and then the row is placed in the worksheet that corresponds with that Type. I dont know if this is even possible.

Thanks in advance!
Bri

Comment: Yea it's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Brianna!

Try this macro (copy and paste it into a new module in VB Editor), see if it fits your need; if it's good, create a button, right-click it, "Assign Macro" then select 'copyRow'.

```
>Sub copyRow()
>
>
>Dim OriginalSheet As String
>Dim TypeColumn As Integer
>Dim StartingLine As Integer
>Dim myType As String
>
>OriginalSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
>
>'edit this number to match the column where the "Type" information is
>TypeColumn = 1
>'edit this part to match the starting point of your records
>StartingLine = 3
>
>Cells(StartingLine, TypeColumn).Select
>
>Counter = 0
>
>Do While ActiveCell.Offset(Counter, 0) <> ""
>
>    myType = ActiveCell.Offset(Counter, 0).Value
>    ActiveCell.Offset(Counter, 0).EntireRow.Copy
>    Sheets(myType).Select
>    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
>    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
>    Sheets(OriginalSheet).Select
>    Cells(StartingLine, TypeColumn).Select
>    Counter = Counter + 1
>
>Loop
>
>'this will exclude the rows already copied
>'you can comment, alter or exclude this line if you wish
>Range(Cells(StartingLine, TypeColumn), Cells(StartingLine + Counter, >TypeColumn)).EntireRow.Delete
>
>End Sub
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey thanks so much for answering me back so quickly! I copied the exact code and changed the Active Sheet Name, the Column number and , the StartingLine number and I am getting an "Object doesnt support theis property or method" on the OriginalSheet = line.. the workbook is saved as an Macro-Enabled Excel sheet

Comment: In this case, you shouldn't change the active sheet name - the purpose of storing it in the "Original_Sheet" variable is for the macro to accept whatever sheet you are on as the first one, so it can paste the rows elsewhere and return to it later. Try leaving this variable as it is, and tell me if that worked.

Comment: Ok.. I changed the variable back to the original like you said, now I am getting an "Subscript out of range" Error on the Sheets(myType).Select line. So sorry Im having all these problems :/

Comment: Not a problem... let me just clarify a question: you want each "Type" to go into a corresponding sheet, isn't it? The way I coded, the sheet name must be EXACTLY the Type on that row, for example, if in row 5 the type is, let's say, "A_1", and the corresponding sheet is named "A", it won't work. Can you confirm if the string (text) in the "Type" cells and the corresponding sheet names is indeed the same? Give me some examples, if you can...

Comment: Yes they are exactly the same the types I have are airplane types so on each row the type will be either 757, 767, 777, A300, MD10-10 and the sheets are names exactly the same